# Auto display the sucategories products in parent counter without "is anchor" option>?

Tags: magento-1.9

is it possible to auto display the subcategories products sum in the parent category counter in magento without using the "Is Anchor" option from the admin panel. As this assigns the subcategories products to the parent but leave the subcategories as the filters.I am only wanted the show the sum of subcategories products counter in the parent category.

Answer (score 1):

Natively, no. But you can imagine a method which does the work (be careful about performance).
Just for curiosity, why you don't want to use anchored categories ?